# Error with mutate_at in dplyr - trying windowed lag by group

Tags: r, dplyr

This is what I have right now:

```
final.df <- all.df %>% dplyr::arrange(customer, date) %>%
  dplyr::select(year, week, customer, date, ltv_score,
                avg_monthly_sales:most_recent_login) %>%
  group_by(customer, year) %>%
  dplyr::mutate_at(c("date"), list(~lead), n = 1) %>%
  data.frame()
```

I am trying to offset everything by one date within the year/customer to backtest predictions - basically have a rolling input of of each group. I found this snippet elsewhere and modified it for what I need but am getting the following error:

```
Error: Input must be a vector, not a <formula> object.
```

Comment: You need two changes `mutate_at(vars('date'), ~ lead(., n = 1))` or if you want to specify without lamdba `mutate_at(vars('date'), lead, n = 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Note that all the `_at`, `_all`, `_if` verbs are deprecated in favour of `across`. For a single column you don't need `mutate_at`/`across`.

```
library(dplyr)

final.df <- all.df %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(customer, date) %>%
  dplyr::select(year, week, customer, date, ltv_score,
                avg_monthly_sales:most_recent_login) %>%
  group_by(customer, year) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(date = lead(date)) %>%
  data.frame()
```